# How to determine which version, if any, of "The Python Imaging Library" is installed in the version of Python that I am running

Tags: macos, python, images, sphinx

I have Python installed on my MacOS Mojave Version 10.14.4

I open the Terminal and run:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

So, my python version is 2.7.10.

I am using Python to render Sphinx documents and notice [the reStructuredText documentation on the images](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image) says:

> If no "height" or "width" options are specified, the Python Imaging
>   Library (PIL) may be used to determine them, if it is installed and
>   the image file is available.

I am not sure if I, or another user, has installed it manually already. So, I would like to know if I have the Python Imaging Library (PIL) installed.

Is there a command I can run to see if Python Imaging Library (PIL) installed? Or perhaps I need to run some kind of code test?

Comment: Looks like you have to manually install [IPL](http://pythonware.com/products/pil/) yourself.  So you need to install it.

Comment: Thanks. I will update the question to make it clear that I cannot be sure whether or not someone has installed it.

Comment: If you cannot find a folder which contains the IPL python files then it's not installed.  [Here](http://effbot.org/media/downloads/PIL-1.1.7a2-py2.5-macosx10.5.mpkg.zip) is the OSX package. If you cannot find the files contained in the package on your system, then IPL isn't installed, use the appropriate tools to search your system.

Comment: So, are you saying that you search your computer for the phrase "PIL-1.1.7a2-py2.5-macosx10.5.mpkg" and it if it is not found then I can be 100% sure that Python Imaging Library (PIL) is not installed?

Comment: I am saying install the package, and determine what files exist, then search your system for another instance of those files.  However, I will repeat my previous statement, unless you installed it yourself it isn't installed.